# How to make this progress bar stop at a specific value that i provide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html and javascript code which shows progress bar. I want it to stop at a specific value. How can i do that?

```js
//var x=document.getElementById("my_canvas");

//var x=24;
// console.log(x);
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

function progressSim() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  if (al >= 100) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of `progressSim()` a simple check would work.

I've added a `limit` var, and a simple check at the start of pregressSim:

`if(al > limit){return false};`

If you change the `limit`, the bar will continue progressing to that new `limit`

If you want don't want to ever continue the progress, you could also end the interval, using:

`if(al > limit){clearTimeout(sim);return false};`

Full example:

```js
//var x=document.getElementById("my_canvas");

//var x=24;
// console.log(x);
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var al = 0;
var limit = 50;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

function progressSim() {
  if(al > limit){return false};
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  if (al >= 100) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.. :)

Comment: @sks No problem, if it fixed your problem you can mark it as accepted with the tick icon next to the votes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable say `var stop = 50`, just clear interval when it reaches the threshold. Check below example.

```js
//var x=document.getElementById("my_canvas");

//var x=24;
// console.log(x);
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

var stop = 50;

var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50);

function progressSim() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  if (al >= stop) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed    #CCC;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is the percentage you may write (refer to [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) which requires [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  var al = 0;
  var start = 4.72;
  var diff;

  function progressSim(end) {
    if (al < end) {
      diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
      al++;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
      ctx.stroke();
    } else {
      // for setInterval you need to use clearInterval
      clearInterval(sim); // NOT clearTimeout(sim);
      // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
    }
  }

  // setInterval(func, delay, arg1 to func: in this case stop at 27%
  var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50, 27);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
```